# Customizing Hubspot form error message (using react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, hubspot

Just wondering if anyone has experince with embedding Hubspot forms using react.js

We have a hubspot form embedded in one of our pages.

This is the current code component which sets up the form:

```
         <HubspotForm
            portalId="xxxxxxx"
            formId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            onSubmit={() => null}
            onReady={() => this.registerListeners()}
            loading={<div>Loading...</div>}
            css={hubspotcss}
            cssClass="hubspotForm"
          />
```

All i want to do is amend the error message for the business email field. So i checked out https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/advanced_form_options

And found the Customize internationalization section to override error messages. From what I could tell I would need to add in this code:

```
          locale="en"
            translations= {
              en= {
                forbiddenEmailDomain= "Please enter a company email address"
              }
          }
```

But when I compile the code I get an error:
error 'locale' is not defined no-undef

Anyone must have an idea what Im doing wrong?
Any information much appreciated

Thanks
Jools

Answer (score 1):

I found that this worked for me after @Ferran Buireu suggestion.

```
translations={{
en:{
    forbiddenEmailDomain: "Please enter a company email address."
   }
}}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm glad it helps. You can mark my answer as correct to close the issue if you want.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you've provided:

> The embed code expects the format `{locale: {messageKey:
>   customMessage}}`. You can override field labels by specifying the
>   label as `{locale: {fieldLabels: {fieldName: customLabel}}}`, and the
>   submit button text using `{locale:{submitText: customSubmitText}}` See
>   the example in the right code pane.

So, the component is expecting an object and your structure doesn't match. It should look like:

```
translations={{
en:{
    forbiddenEmailDomain: "Please enter a company email address."
   }
}}
```

Notice the closures to open a subobject inside.

References [here](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/advanced_form_options).

Comment: Thanks for that I used your method to correct it and found that it worked with double braces:

                  translations={{
                    en:{
                      forbiddenEmailDomain: "Please enter a company email address."
                    }
                  }}